# Best way to create a numpy array of custom objects from data arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose you have a python class which encapsulates some data:

```
import numpy
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: float
    b: float
```

One can create an instance of `A` containing arrays instead of simple floats:

```
a_vals = numpy.linspace(0, 1)
b_vals = numpy.linspace(0, 1)

ma, mb = numpy.meshgrid(a_vals, b_vals, indexing="ij")

# Now the instance
a_instance = A(ma, mb)
```

Alternatively, one can create an array of `A` instances

```
a_instances = numpy.empty((50, 50), dtype=object)
for i in range(50):
    for j in range(50):
        a_instances[i, j] = A(a_vals[i], b_vals[j])
```

But this seems to be much more cumbersome, with actual loops being involved. Is there a better way to create the array of `A` instances over `a_vals` and `b_vals` (or their meshgrids)? What is the way of doing this intended by numpy?

Comment: `np.vectorize` has a performance disclaimer.  Typically for small test case, iteration as you do is faster; but `vectorize` tends to scale better.  In your (50,50) sample `vectorize` is modestly faster (2ms vs 3).  For making objects like this, `np.frompyfunc(A,2,1)` is even better.

Comment: To get the `a` attribute of your instances you'll need to do something like: `np.vectorize(lambda x:x.a)(a_instances)`.   Object dtype arrays don't have the speed, or math facilities, of regular numeric arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I'd caution that "intended by numpy" tends to be to avoid `dtype=object` and to instead use a `(X, Y, 2)` shaped array.

If you do want to get a shape `(X, Y)` array of `A` objects, then [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) could work:

```
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: float
    b: float

a_vals = np.arange(3)
b_vals = np.arange(3)

out = np.vectorize(A)(a_vals[:, None], b_vals[None, :])
```

out:

```
array([[A(a=0, b=0), A(a=0, b=1), A(a=0, b=2)],
       [A(a=1, b=0), A(a=1, b=1), A(a=1, b=2)],
       [A(a=2, b=0), A(a=2, b=1), A(a=2, b=2)]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numpy.vectorize function to create an array of instances of class A over a_vals and b_vals. This function takes a Python function as input and returns a new function that can operate on NumPy arrays. Here’s an example:

```
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: float
    b: float

a_vals = np.linspace(0, 1)
b_vals = np.linspace(0, 1)

ma, mb = np.meshgrid(a_vals, b_vals, indexing="ij")

def create_instance(a, b):
    return A(a, b)

create_instance_vectorized = np.vectorize(create_instance)

a_instances = create_instance_vectorized(ma, mb)

# Print the resulting array of instances
print(a_instances)
```

This will create a 2D array of instances of class A with the values of a and b attributes taken from the meshgrid of a_vals and b_vals